# Admin wysiwig thumbnails flooding server

Tags: magento-1.6, image, wysiwyg

I've noticed that when you open the wysiwig image uploader it generates a whole bunch of PHP requests to generate thumbnails for those images. In my case it immediately kicks off about 100 requests. This makes my server grind to a halt as PHP tries to process all those requests.

Any way I can limit or prevent this?

Comment: I see two ways: Either open more often the  uploader, so the image are generated more often or just pregenerate them automatically. Ah no, a third (and bad way) you can change the template, so the original pics are loaded instead of the thumbnails